# Port ProModel Process Simulator model to Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Any advice on how to port a Process Simulator simulation model to Anylogic ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow!  In order to better help in answering your question, it helps if you show some working of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated import for that. So you will have to re-do the model object by object. The process library in AnyLogic seems very similar so you shouldn't have too much difficulty.

good luck